# Permission Denied for wrong user when I use "git push"

Tags: git, permissions, repository, commit

I was using git with my username and email and everything was working well. For one specific project I used different username and email to push some commits for another person. I set back git config user.name and git config user.email how they were but when I use git push it says "Permission to repo denied for "username of that person">". How can I solve this problem to make git use my username and email how they were.

Comment: AFAIK git username and email are unrelated to pushing. Make sure your ssh, or other authentication, details are correct.

Comment: I know but I changed them back using git config --global user.name and git config --global user.email how they were before

Comment: `git config` is not for authentication.

Comment: The SSH key you are using to push with is not attached to that repo. You need to re-set the SSH key

Comment: So, why do you think is throwing that permission error ?

Comment: Please share the actual error, and also the remote URL?

Comment: remote: Permission to <repo> denied to <user>. The user which git is using to push commits to my repo refers to the user which I configured to push commits on another project how I mentioned in my quesion  @evolutionxbox